# graph theory term for highway exit that if you miss will massively increase distance to destination?

Tags: graph-theory

usually when driving with GPS you can miss an exit, and GPS will recalculate another route with similar distance to destination. Perhaps it will make you turn around and go back. But, maybe after the missed exit there is a very long road stretch without any way to go back. So if you miss it, the distance to destination will increase massively.

Is this sort of situation well-known standard topic in graph theory? Not sure about precise definitions, perhaps "edge whose removal from directed connected graph significantly increases distance from A to B or perhaps significantly increases graph diameter?" Is there special terminology, algorithms etc for this?

Answer (score 0):

You could positively weigh the edges of the graph to represent the distance that needs to be traveled by taking a particular path from some origin vertex $O$ to some other destination vertex $D$. Then you find the shortest path through a simple minimization problem: minimize the sum of the weights of each edge of a particular path from $O$ to $D$, over all possible paths from $O$ to $D$.

Given the total weight of the shortest path on the original graph, you could then determine the effect of removing some edge(here missing your exit or turn is similar to it not existing at all) by recomputing the next shortest path on the graph without that edge and comparing the weights.

Comment: I dont think diameter would be of much use to you here, rather weighted graphs. Also, see here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem